# HTML String and encoding

Tags: javascript, html, encoding

I think I'm chasing my tail a bit here and would appreciate someone setting me straight. In my Javascript program, I need to POST a HTML string using AJAX to my PHP server. The HTML string may have embedded image data in it.

Part 1: Simple case - HTML string is only text - for example -  "Mmiz's question"

```
<p>Mmiz&#39;s question</p>
```

If I do nothing wrt encoding, the POST seems to clobber everything after the apostrophe and it's just "Mmiz" on the server side. Using escape() did not fix the problem either! What should I be doing to safely transport the html string to the server?

Part 2: If there is image data in the html, I base 64 URL safe encode the image data using:

```
encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/'/g,"%27").replace(/"/g,"%22");
```

Is this the right way to go about it?

Thanks for the guidance!

Mmiz

Comment: As for part 1, you should use encodeURIComponent also, that will prevent the server script to take data after `&` as a seperated field.

Comment: So following your suggestion - in my jquery code I did the following  encodeURIComponent(escape(html_str)). Then on the PHP server side, I decode it thusly: urldecode(encod_str). No change. Still comes out as MMiz&#39;s on the server side.  Oh -I have ContentType specified as:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are sending your data either as GET data or form data. In either case, `&` marks the end of the parameter and that start of the next one. You MUST encode this. Additionally, it is a good idea to encode other characters too, such as using `encodeURIComponent`.

That said, you might want to look into an alternative method. For instance, I like to just submit my data straight to the server with no complications, so the request would look like:

```
POST /somefile.php HTTP/1.0
Host: example.com
Content-Type: text/plain     -- or some relevant type, like application/json
Content-Length: 13

Hello, World!
```

Then on the server side, in PHP in this case, I can just use `file_get_contents("php://input")` to retrieve the data, no problems whatsoever.